# On the quadratic reciprocity law?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In the Quadratic Reciprocity Law
$$\exists x\in\Bbb{N}\quad x^2\equiv p\pmod q\iff\exists y\in\Bbb{N}\quad y^2\equiv q\pmod p$$ if $p\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod4$.

Is there any relation between $x$ and $y$ in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what relation you look for.

E.g., $x$ and $y$ may be viewed as reductions of the same residue $z$ modulo $q$ and $p$, respectively, where $z^2\equiv p+q\pmod{pq}$.

Comment: $$13^2=5\bmod 41$$ $$13^2=4\bmod5$$ but $$13^2\neq 46\bmod205$$

Comment: should be $z^2\equiv\pm(p+q)\pmod{pq}$ I think.

Comment: @Turbo: I do not quite follow your first comment. As of $\pm$, notice that $x$ and $y$ (as well as $z$) are defined up to a sign, so you can think of them as reductions of $\pm z$ if you like.

Comment: @MaxAleksetev I just want to know this.

Comment: Assume $p$ and $q$ are large primes $1\bmod 4$ and assume $g<p<q$ generates both $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ and $\Bbb Z_q^\times$. 

Then if $g^{2r}=p\bmod q$ it seems that $g^{2r\bmod(p-1)}=\pm q\bmod p$ should hold. Is this true?

What if we had $x^2g^{2r}=p\bmod q$ instead? Will $x^2g^{2r\bmod(p-1)}=\pm q\bmod p$ hold?

Can we generalize this to common generators without $g<p<q$ restriction and finally what if $g$ generates only one of $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ and $\Bbb Z_q^\times$?

Comment: @Turbo: Test your questions numerically -- this is the fastest way to disprove incorrect assumptions.

Comment: I checked it is incorrect. However assume $p$ and $q$ are large primes $1\bmod 4$ and assume $g<p<q$ generates both $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ and $\Bbb Z_q^\times$. 

If $g^{2r}=p\bmod q$ when is $g^{2r\bmod(p-1)}=\pm q\bmod p$ true?

Comment: @Turbo: E.g., when $g^{2r} \equiv p+q \pmod{pq}$ (as suggested in the answer above).

Comment: @MaxAkekseyev I tried a few examples I cannot find precisely when $g^{2r}=p\bmod q$ would imply $g^{2r\bmod(p-1)}=\pm q\bmod p$. For example $23^{26}\bmod149=113$ but $23^{26}\bmod113= 104\not\equiv149\bmod113$. Is there any way to guess at what $r'$ we have $g^{2r'}=149\bmod113$? Also $23^{26}\equiv4285\bmod16387\not\equiv(113+149)\bmod16387$ and $16387=113\times149$.